# Can you find $\lim_{x\to0}x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ without sandwich theorem?

Tags: calculus, limits

The lesson I'm doing is solving 
$\lim_{x\to0}x^2\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)$
with sandwich theorem like so :
$$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}-x^2\leq\displaystyle\lim_{x\to0}x^2\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)\leq\displaystyle\lim_{x\to 0}x^2$$
When I first look at this though my thought was to use the properties of lim and do this :
$\lim_{x\to0}x^2 = 0$ and times that by $\lim_{x\to0}\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)$
And if I'm not an idiot then this says that $0\sin(1/0)$ is going to equal $0$ which is the right answer.
Does that make sense? Instead of bothering with sandwich theorem you could just pull apart the $x^2$ and $\sin(1/x)$, input the $0$ of the limit and not even have to bother with the sine.

Comment: the trouble is $\lim_{x\to 0}\sin(1/x)$ is undefined.

Comment: Right but can't you "skip" that since it will be multiplied by 0? That would seem logical to me. Besides in the lessons they are saying dividing by 0 gives infinity.

Comment: Note that properties of limits don't apply here as one of the factors $x^2$ tends to $0$ and the limit of other factor $\sin(1/x)$ does not exist. So you can either go for sandwich theorem or just use the definition of limit directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this doesn't work. As

$$\lim_{x\to0}\sin\left(\frac1x\right)$$ does not exist, *you may not invoke the product rule*.

Using the same reasoning, we could write

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac xx=\left(\lim_{x\to0}x\right)\left(\lim_{x\to0}\frac 1x\right)\color{red}{=0}$$ "because the first limit is $0$ and we don't care that the second does not exist".

---

If you claim that "but it will work because the sine is bounded", you are in fact implicitly using a sandwich argument:

$$a<\sin x<b,$$ then

$$ax^2<x^2\sin x<bx^2$$ proves the limit $0$.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 0}\sin(1/x)=\lim\limits_{X\rightarrow +\infty}\sin(X)$ doesn't exist. You can also write that $|x^2\sin(1/x)|\leqslant x^2\underset{x\rightarrow 0}{\longrightarrow} 0$

Comment: But $0 * sin(infinity)$ would equal zero. Doesn't matter if sin(infinity) doesn't really exist, it must be between -1 and 1 right?

Comment: The fact that $\sin$ is between $-1$ and $1$ is used in the sandwich theorem, what you want to do, the sandwich theorem does it rigorously. You can't manipulate things that doesn't exist... For instance $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow +\infty}{(\cos x-\cos x)}=0$ but you can't write that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow +\infty}{(\cos x-\cos x)}=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow +\infty}{\cos x}-\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow +\infty}{\cos x}$ because it doesn't make sense, as $1+1=3$ doesn't make sense either.

Comment: What do you mean? That would make perfect sense. infinity = infinity and cos(x) - cos(x) = 0.
And besides 0 x anything is 0. so 0 x sin(any number) = 0

Comment: Infinity is unpredictable, in fact it is not a number so the statement $0\times\sin(any\ number)=0$ does not apply here.

Comment: $0 * anything = 0$ Right? We don't need to consider the second half as long as there is nothing that would be added after the *

Comment: But here $x^2\neq 0$ ! it is a limit and it is not necessary reached.

Comment: But the first thing to do with limits is to plug in the number and see if it works, in this case it can and therefore is reached?

Comment: You seem to confound limit and continuity, for instance $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}{\frac{1}{n}}=0$ but $1/n\neq 0$ forall $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$.

Comment: @DerekC. $0\cdot\text{anything}=0$ is wrong.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Could you go on?

Comment: @DerekC.read my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think It make sense. see whatever is in sine function it will always give a value from [-1,1] and if we multiply it by a number which is almost zero we will get zero.

Comment: This is a restatement of the sandwich theorem in disguise.